# How does pyspark perform union?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If I have a code like this:

```
def my_func(df):
    df1 = trans1(df)

    df2 = trans2(df1)
    df3 = trans3(df1)

    df4 = df2.unionAll(df3)

    return df4
```

And I run a `df.collect()`on the result of the function while not having persisted anything. How many times will the operations in '''trans1''' be run? Once or twice? Thanks!

Comment: Twice, running in parallel. If you add `df1.cache()` anywhere before `collect()` - then once.

Answer (score 0):

Coming into your question In your `DF` there is no `Action` .
So it will not perform anything .

But hypothetically I am taking an example you have performed `cache`

```
df.cache().storageLevel
```

Post that you have performed some `count action` .

`Caching/persistence` is **lazy** when used with `Dataset API` so you have to trigger the `caching` using `count operator` or similar that in turn submits a **Spark job**.

[image]

In your case even after `union` there is no `action` if you have used action to `write into disk`.

**Yes. Only actions (like saving to an external storage) can trigger the persistence for future reuse.**

you can check out `Storage tab in web UI`  about it.

Comment: As I wrote in my question (sorry if it was not clear) I assume I am running a collect action on the result of the function and nothing is persisted in cache.

Comment: There is no precise answer to this problem statement . If your data is too small then in this case you are applying only one action in which DAG will reuse the result by  auto broadcast. If your data is huge then it might need to be recomputed .

Answer (score 0):

> Twice

All transformations in spark all `lazily` evaluated which basically creates a lineage of instructions, and once an action is performed, it traverses the lineage from bottom to top until it finds the materialised data.

Since `df1` is not materialised it will perform the same operation twice for two different linages. If `df1` is persisted, first graph will perform full transformation whereas second will do only further computation by reusing it. You can see it in DAG and SQL plan tab.

Please note that it is not necessary to always cache the data. Sometimes caching can cost more than re-computation, therefore you should cache the if and only if the computation cost is higher.